# Input Data From User of Any Data Type

Tags: c#, .net

Question :- How can we take input from the user of any type and check that data and return or print a message to a user that he/she has input a string, integer or float type data ?

Is there any data type which can take any type of data. If not then how can we accomplish this with another way?

Comment: How is the user communicating this input to you? Through a Windows Forms UI? A WPF UI? `Console.In`? Is he scrawling it on a bloodsmeared parchment and pinning it to your door with a dagger, or etching it on a meteor that's on a collision course with a sleepy little town in Manitoba? The last one is the easiest.

Comment: It is a Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from a input you ever will read a string.

If you want to discover if the string inputed parses with a specific data type, you can use "try parse".

For exemple:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(inputValue, out number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is inputting data through Console.In, it's going to come in the form of a string.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, if you want to see what data that is, you have a couple ways to check using TryParse

```
while (true) {
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    float f;
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out i)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is of type int");
    } else if (float.TryParse(input, out f)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is of type float");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is of type string");
    }
}
```

I wouldn't use Double.TryParse() because it will parse both ints and floats, and tell you the input is of type double.

```
double d;
Double.TryParse("1", out d) //true
Double.TryParse("1.0", out d) //true
```

when you might want an input of "1" to return type int, and input of type "1.0" to return float.

Comment: Actually I want to return a message that you have entered this type of data but this code is not working like this.

Comment: What's not working? The above code should take a line of input, parse it to int, float, or string, and print the type. What's likely happening is you're running this, inputting something, and it closes immediately. I'll change it to a while(true) loop and see if that works better

Comment: Okay... Thanks **d-stewart** actually It was returning double always.. but now it's working.. after putting the parse.int part at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, I realized a little bit late that trying to parse a double would be problematic. The above code should work as you intend it to.